# Node.JS - Fork blocks parent loop execution

Tags: node.js, windows

I'm trying to 'multi-thread' using fork and starting up a new process. The problem is once  the program is executed and the first fork executes the whole parent code is blocked by the executing fork.

I thought fork just returns a process object?

Here is a stripped back version of the code I am using:

```
// I am looping a multi-dimensional array and sending an object to the fork IPC.
let array = ["a0", "a1", "a2"];

// Blocking Code
arr.forEach((arrayItem) => { 
    const forked = fork('./child.js');

    // IPC code to send object...

    // Capture IPC child messages
    forked.on('message', (msg) => {
        // Handle message...
    });
});
```

**It's worth adding what I want to happen for carity!**

Using forEach I'd be able to create multiple child processes that all communicate over IPC without the parent execution block.

Comment: How do you conclude that the parent process is being blocked by the `fork`? How many processes are you starting (in other words: how many items does `array` hold in your actual situation)?

Comment: @robertklep Becuase my IPC only returns messages from the first child. [Child 0] Blah blah... I added a more tedious task in child process and that makes it an running task. I only get messages from the first child.

Comment: There's nothing inherently wrong with the code that you're showing.

Comment: Hmm strange... Could it be caused by a blocking function the child possibly. Such as setInterval or setTimeout?

Comment: Both those functions aren't blocking, but even if they were, they wouldn't cause a parent process to block. However, if your child processes perform blocking operations (like calculations), those might prevent `process.send()` to be handled properly.

Comment: Strange... I'll double check my code. Racking my brains to understand why it's happend. Thanks for the help @robertklep. I'm new to Node.JS so still understanding some bits.

Comment: @robertklep ahhh, maybe that's why because I open connection to socket in fork. then possibly the `process.send()` is not being executed

Comment: Any I/O that you perform in a Node process is generally non-blocking.

Comment: @robertklep Interesting. I'll take another look. Most likely I've done something wrong. I had spent all day on it yesterday. Fresh eyes might make me spot it! Thanks for the comments/help!